# echo degree sign (tempature) and save it to a text file utf8?

Tags: php, utf-8, escaping

cant get it to work when i add the degree° sign, it works fine without the degree sign ° ,  i tried to escape the degree sign by adding a slash infront if it no luck. Is echo a degree sign  and save it into the text file?  (Not html, raw text file)

```
$Temperature = "22";
$Temperature = "$Temperature°";
echo $Temperature;
```

also want to write to a text file in utf8 (i assume?)

```
$file = "gettemp.txt";
file_put_contents($file, $Temperature);
```

returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper HTML code for the degree symbol.

```
<?php
// Save the degree as an integer.
$temp = 22;

// Create one degree symbol for HTML and one for the Text file.
$degree_html = '&deg;';
$degree_text = '°';

// Echo to a terminal screen.
echo $temp . $degree_text, "\n";

// Echo to a webpage.
echo $temp . $degree_html, "\n";

// Save to the text file.
file_put_contents('file.txt', $temp . $degree_text);
```

Comment: text file is not HTML file ,. its raw text

Comment: Are you echoing out to a web page or a terminal?

Comment: to a text file or terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML entity `&deg` for degree sign .

```
   $Temperature = "22 &deg";
    echo $Temperature;

    $file = "gettemp.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $Temperature);
```

Comment: for adding degree sign in txt (Window) you have to press `ALT+0176` than it will show in txt file .

Comment: yes i know ALT+0176 but the php code is going to write the degree symbol

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer
file_put_contents($file.txt, utf8_encode($Temperature));